# Harry Potter Fanfic: Harry lives with Snape and has to be a little

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, severus-snape, draco-malfoy

Okay, so, this question might have been asked already but I’ve been looking for a couple days for the fan fiction. I can’t remember if it’s on FF.net or AO3, but Harry has to live with Snape, I think over the summer. He finds out that in order to live with Snape, he has to be a little or Regress his age or something. I’m not sure why I read it, or how I found it. But later on in the story he finds out that Draco is also a little and meets him again, but I think Draco is older than he is as a little. If anyone knows it would be appreciated, it’s driving me crazy!

Comment: Just to be clear, "be a little" means to be transformed to a younger age?

Comment: Yes, I believe so

Comment: :-D I think only you can answer what you mean by that phrase.

Comment: Is this age play sexual?

Comment: Yeah it’s just the phrasing I remember from the fic, and no it wasn’t sexual at all